# Having error when downloading the ZIP file from the S3-Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3

When I am trying to download the ZIP files from the S3 buckets it is showing some error

My Code

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'picarro-da-gis'
file = 'ReteGasBari/10082021/Incoming/20211008_ReteGasBari.zip'
filename = '/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Downloads/'

# Downloading ZIP file
client.download_file(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=file,
    Filename=filename
)
```

My error

```
File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/zip_download.py", line 12, in <module>
    client.download_file(
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 190, in download_file
    return transfer.download_file(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 326, in download_file
    future.result()
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 139, in __call__
    return self._execute_main(kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/tasks.py", line 162, in _execute_main
    return_value = self._main(**kwargs)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/download.py", line 673, in _main
    osutil.rename_file(fileobj.name, final_filename)
  File "/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Connect-Automation/s3-Env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/s3transfer/utils.py", line 284, in rename_file
    rename_file(current_filename, new_filename)
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Downloads/.b3aAB3c8' -> '/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Downloads/'
```

Can anyone help for me?

I need to download the ZIP file from the S3 bucket using path

Comment: `filename = '/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Downloads/something.zip'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `filename` points to a directory. You need to add a specific filename for the downloaded object:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

bucket = 'picarro-da-gis'
file = 'ReteGasBari/10082021/Incoming/20211008_ReteGasBari.zip'
filename = '/Users/vithushan/Desktop/S3-Downloads/downloaded.zip'

# Downloading ZIP file
client.download_file(
    Bucket=bucket,
    Key=file,
    Filename=filename
)
```